# how can I use multiple paths in php if statement

Tags: php

```
<?php if (preg_match('/\/contact\//', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) === 1): ?>
<a href="/">link</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I'm trying to add multiple folders into the same statement like /contact/ and /news/, so the content inside the statement will appear in both folders.

I tried `(preg_match('/\/contact\//', '/\/news\//', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])`, but it returned errors.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use A `|` (OR) operator in regexp.

```
<?php if (preg_match('/\/(contact|news)\//', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) === 1): ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not how `preg_match` works. First argument is REGEX and the second one is a subject. Use regex `|` operator

```
<?php if (preg_match('/\/(contact|news)\//', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) === 1): ?>
   <a href="/">link</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Ah regex.. of course. I feel dumb since I've been using that in htaccess, and didn't think of it. Thank you very much.

Comment: No worries :-) We are here to help each other